# ZeroMQ doesn't spot libsodium

Tags: zeromq, libsodium

I'm hoping to get the CurveCP functionality working within ZeroMQ ØMQ.  I'm using CentOS as the underlying OS.

After downloading and running ZeroMQ, I've done the usual `./configure`, `make` and `sudo make install`.  Then running `make check` returned many test passes, but stated:

```
 libsodium not installed, skipping CURVE test
```

So `sudo yum install libsodium` and `sudo ldconfig`, then `make clean`, and the commands above.  But next time I ran the `make check`, the CURVE test is skipped, again reporting no libsodium.

Looking at the tests, I see `test_security_curve.cpp` has `#ifndef HAVE_LIBSODIUM` and that preprocessor definition appears to be driving the 'no libsodium' skip.

`./configure --with-libsodium` as per [this page](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues/912) reports `libsodium is not installed`

`./configure --with-libsodium=/home/eng/work/libsodium-master  --with-libsodium-include-dir=/home/eng/work/libsodium-master/src/libsodium/include --with-libsodium-lib-dir=/usr/lib64` reports `libsodium is not installed`.

**Solution**

In order to get this working, installing libsodium via YUM did not give a version of libsodium viable for a zeromq build.  It needed a real build of libsodium, which in turn required a recent copy of autoconf.

```
curl -OL http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/autoconf/autoconf-2.69.tar.gz
tar xzf autoconf-2.69.tar.gz
cd autoconf-2.69
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig  
cd ../libsodium-master
./autogen.sh
./configure
make 
sudo make install
cd ../libzmq-master
sudo ./configure --with-libsodium=/home/eng/work/libsodium-master  --with-libsodium-include-dir=/home/eng/work/libsodium-master/src/libsodium/include --with-libsodium-lib-dir=/usr/lib64
sudo make
make check  
sudo make install
```

Comment: configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-libsodium-lib-dir

Comment: Thanks, it's helpful. In addition automake installation was also needed for me http://askubuntu.com/questions/430706/installing-autotools-autoconf